# replace a simple forloop with linq

Tags: linq, foreach

I want to know how to replace a simple foreach loop with linq. I'm not looking for answers about 2 or more loops....It's specifically for a single foreach loop..

```
List<string> strlist=new List<string>();    
strlist.Add("Hello");
strlist.Add("World");

//The main "to be linq" here...

foreach(string str in strlist)
{
Console.Writeline(str);
}
```

Now how do I write this simple loop in 1 line?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The advice of Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) is not to write such loops as expressions.

Only use query expressions if the code does not have side-effects and produces a value.

In this case, you're looping to repeat a statement, which has a side-effect on the console and doesn't return values. So a foreach loop is clearer and is designed specifically for this purpose.

On the other hand, an action (which may have side-effects) can be regarded as a pure value *before it is executed*. So here's a list of numbers:

```
List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
```

From that we make a list of actions:

```
List<Action> actions = numbers.Select(n => Console.WriteLine(n)).ToList();
```

Although we're dealing with actions that have side effects, we aren't actually running them at all, so any further manipulations on the content of that list are not side-effecting. Then finally when we have the list we need, we can use a forloop to execute it:

```
foreach (var a in actions)
    a();
```

And that is such a simple pattern, it could be argued that a `RunAll` extension method on `IEnumerable<Action>` would be no bad thing. Indeed, the .NET framework has this concept built into it: a multicast delegate is a single thing you can call which executes a bunch of delegates on a list. In the most common use cases (events), those delegates have side-effects.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method:

```
strlist.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

As pointed out in the comments this works only for `List<T>`. If your datasource is an `IEnumerable<T>` you could write an extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> inputList, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in inputList)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just pointing out that only works with List<T> (which is the case in the question posed), while LINQ stuff generally works with IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Yes, but as there's no equivalent for `IEnumerable<T>` it should be pretty trivial to implement an extension method for this.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use a `ForEach` method (either on `List<T>` or your own on `IEnumerable<T>`) - but it's not very "idiomatically LINQ-y".

LINQ is based on functional principles - so the functions you provide are usually expected to be side-effect free. `ForEach` is pointless if the function *is* side-effect free, so the two approaches are in tension.

Eric Lippert has a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) providing more details.

Basically there's nothing wrong with using a `foreach` when you want to *do* something with the data; LINQ is meant for *querying* the data. Typically you build up a LINQ query and then use a `foreach` statement to *use* the data.